# Compare two files with two columns and remove duplicate row from 2nd file in shell script

Tags: shell

Please find the below example for my question:

File1.txt:

```
A|6359454|102951|FAR|976391300|12/02/2014 12:00:00 AM|2|12/02/2014 09:43:42 AM
B|6353591|102952|HEN|42217A106|11/30/2014 12:00:00 AM|10|12/02/2014 12:25:16 AM
A|6358494|102952|HEN|42217A106|12/02/2014 12:00:00 AM|10|12/02/2014 02:04:23 PM
A|6358496|102983|NAI|63633D104|12/02/2014 12:00:00 AM|6|12/02/2014 12:59:04 PM
B|6347496|102999|ACB|69360B107|11/28/2014 12:00:00 AM|1|12/02/2014 05:59:23 AM
A|6359347|102999|ACB|69360B107|12/02/2014 12:00:00 AM|2|12/02/2014 05:59:23 AM
C|6337344|103010|OAC|22002T108|11/25/2014 12:00:00 AM|10|12/01/2014 08:48:01 AM
```

File2.txt:

```
B|6359454|102951|FAR|976391300|12/02/2014 12:00:00 AM|2|12/02/2014 09:43:42 AM
B|6353591|102952|HEN|42217A106|11/30/2014 12:00:00 AM|10|12/02/2014 12:25:16 AM
A|6358494|102952|HEN|42217A106|12/02/2014 12:00:00 AM|10|12/02/2014 02:04:23 PM
C|6337344|103010|OAC|22002T108|11/25/2014 12:00:00 AM|10|12/01/2014 08:48:01 AM
A|6358496|102983|NAI|63633D104|12/02/2014 12:00:00 AM|6|12/02/2014 12:59:04 PM
B|6353613|103061|SAT|875465106|11/30/2014 12:00:00 AM|7|12/01/2014 07:22:18 PM
A|6355261|103061|SAT|875465106|12/01/2014 12:00:00 AM|7|12/01/2014 07:22:18 PM
B|6347496|102999|ACB|69360B107|11/28/2014 12:00:00 AM|1|12/02/2014 05:59:23 AM
A|6358506|103060|PQS|737464107|12/02/2014 12:00:00 AM|9|12/02/2014 04:24:43 AM
C|6337352|103065|OAI|681936100|11/25/2014 12:00:00 AM|6|11/26/2014 04:30:42 AM
C|6359347|102999|ACB|69360B107|12/02/2014 12:00:00 AM|2|12/02/2014 05:59:23 AM
```

Desired Output:

File3.txt:

```
B|6353613|103061|SAT|875465106|11/30/2014 12:00:00 AM|7|12/01/2014 07:22:18 PM
A|6355261|103061|SAT|875465106|12/01/2014 12:00:00 AM|7|12/01/2014 07:22:18 PM
A|6358506|103060|PQS|737464107|12/02/2014 12:00:00 AM|9|12/02/2014 04:24:43 AM
C|6337352|103065|OAI|681936100|11/25/2014 12:00:00 AM|6|11/26/2014 04:30:42 AM
```

I'd like to compare file1 and file2 using their 4th,6th columns and remove the entire line from file2 where they match in file 1. I'd also like to save the results to a 3rd file.

I tried

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4,$6];next};!(a[$4,$6])' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

but output is printing 2 file

Thanks in advance

Comment: So wich specific problem do you have with your code ? What have you tried ?

Comment: i tried with awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4,$6];next};!(a[$4,$6])' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt but output is printing 2 file

Comment: Always provides what you have done if you don't want the downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below command and getting correct output.

awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$4,$6]++;next} !(a[$4,$6])' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
perl -we ' my %seen;
           open my $fh1, "<", $ARGV[0];
           while (<$fh1>) {
               my @fields = split /[|]/, $_;
               ++$seen{"$fields[3]|$fields[5]"};
           }
           close $fh1;
           open my $fh2, "<", $ARGV[1];
           while (<$fh2>) {
               my @fields = split /[|]/, $_;
               print unless $seen{"$fields[3]|$fields[5]"};
           }
' File1.txt File2.txt > File3.txt
```

Comment: i want to do using shell scripting

Comment: @user3796869: Nonsense. The shell script that you posted is a single AWK command; this shell script is a single Perl command. If yours counts as "using shell scripting", then so does mine!

Comment: ,sorry if my comment hurts you i am new to shell scripting